# Using scanf to read in certain amount of characters in C?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am having trouble accepting input from a text file. My program is supposed to read in a string specified by the user and the length of that string is determined at runtime. It works fine when the user is running the program (manually inputting the values) but when I run my teacher's text file, it runs into an infinite loop.

For this example, it fails when I am taking in 4 characters and his input in his file is "ABCDy". "ABCD" is what I am supposed to be reading in and 'y' is supposed to be used later to know that I should restart the game. Instead when I used scanf to read in "ABCD", it also reads in the 'y'. Is there a way to get around this using scanf, assuming I won't know how long the string should be until runtime?

Answer (score 18):

Normally, you'd use something like `"%4c"` or `"%4s"` to read a maximum of 4 characters (the difference is that `"%4c"` reads the next 4 characters, regardless, while `"%4s"` skips leading whitespace and stops at a whitespace if there is one).

To specify the length at run-time, however, you have to get a bit trickier since you can't use a string literal with "4" embedded in it. One alternative is to use `sprintf` to create the string you'll pass to `scanf`:

```
char buffer[128];

sprintf(buffer, "%%%dc", max_length);
scanf(buffer, your_string);
```

I should probably add: with `printf` you can specify the width or precision of a field dynamically by putting an asterisk (`*`) in the format string, and passing a variable in the appropriate position to specify the width/precision:

```
int width = 10;
int precision = 7;
double value = 12.345678910;

printf("%*.*f", width, precision, value);
```

Given that `printf` and `scanf` format strings are quite similar, one might think the same would work with `scanf`. Unfortunately, this is not the case--with `scanf` an asterisk in the conversion specification indicates a value that should be scanned, but not converted. That is to say, something that must be present in the input, but its value won't be placed in any variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
scanf("%4s", str)
```

Comment: It is still reading in the y at the end. And I don't know how long the value may be.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use fread, where you can set a read limit:

```
char string[5]={0};
if( fread(string,(sizeof string)-1,1,stdin) )
  printf("\nfull readed: %s",string);
else
  puts("error");
```

Answer (score -2):

You might consider simply looping over calls to [getc()](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/getc.html).

Comment: That's analogous to telling somebody who wants to draw exactly 80 pixels to call putpixel 80 times. both are a bad idea in all but academic and benchmarking contexts, since instead of a single request to the server, you are bombarding it with arbitrary number of requests, each of which is larger in size than the result.